# what are the factors in the project which decides what backend technology to use?

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Can someone please explain me on what scenario we can  choose hibernate or jdbctemplate what factors of project are underconsiderations?

Comment: 1) choose one you know. if you don't know both, learn one,(throw coin) and see if it will suit you. no? choose other.
2) this is not related to MVC
3) hibernate wraps jdbc...

Comment: thanks for you view